# Should we create a blog for TGO

Tags: discussion

We can apply and get a Blog for TGO.  I've already seen several good topics for blog material, and I think that it would go a long way towards helping build our user base.  However to get a blog we need writers and the admins cannot do that alone.

I'd like to have about 12 potential posts queued up before we apply for the blog.  Please discuss any thoughts.  If you are willing to blog please reply with a topic you would be willing to write an entry for.

(Remember to reply below if you'll blog, we need volunteers).

Comment: [Some interesting thoughts on site blogs](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/573)

Answer (score 4):

Good idea! I support this.

A blog would allow us to take existing questions and perhaps flesh them out more, or even share stories about our experiences in the outdoors.  Perhaps one could write about their hunting trip with pictures or how they survived an unexpected storm in the wilderness.  Like, a `Lessons Learned` Series or something.

We can also write about more subjective things, such as why fixed blades are better than folding knives or etc.

Answer (score 3):

Is this still going ahead? I'd be willing to write an article or 2 - letterboxing / geocaching would be my topic of choice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably be able to pull together a post on the essentials of camping with children (as I do it **a lot**)

Answer (score 2):

I think I could write a worthwile post about rain gear – why (or when) membranes are better than a plain old raincoat, how they work and what are their limits.