# Is the idea of a blog still going ahead?

Tags: discussion

As in the title really, are we going to create a blog and if so, when abouts will it pop up? The question came up a while back and there were some volunteers but nothing much else seems to have happened.

Personally I think it'd be good to get this up and running!

Comment: Yes, there is still the intent.  I need to revisit and get it moving.

Comment: @RussellSteen Awesome, good to hear.

Answer (score 3):

The process for getting a blog is [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/). The process is basically:

1. Raise the idea on the child meta.
2. Define the scope and purpose of the blog.
3. Recruit contributors.
4. Plan a schedule.

We've obviously got 1 covered. 3 and to a lesser extent 2 are being covered on [Russell's original post](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/307/18).  I think once we get the 12 posts he was looking for planned, we can plan the schedule (4), and then we ask the community team for the blog.  So come up with some ideas for blog posts and post them in the other thread, and strong-arm some other members here to do the same.